# SQLでURLのパラメータを正規表現REGEXP_REPLACEで消して集計する

Tags: sql, 正規表現

SQLにてURLの一部のパラメータを消して、集計を行っています。

例えば、下記のようなURL/PVがあるとします。

| URL | PV |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa/bbbb/cccc?parameter=0&is_true=0 | 1 |
| aaaa/bbbb/cccc?parameter=0 | 2 |

`is_true=0` は無視したいので、上記のデータを元に以下のように集計したいです。

| URL | PV |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa/bbbb/cccc?parameter=0 | 3 |

正規表現で `&is_true=0` を消すため、REGEXP_REPLACEで下記のように書いてみたのですがうまくいきません。

`REGEXP_REPLACE('URL',r'(.+)\&is\_true\=0','')`

全体のSQLはこんな雰囲気です。

```
SELECT
    t.date,
    hits.page.pagePath AS pagepath,
    COUNT (URL) AS pageviews
FROM
    `aaaa.ga_sessions_*` AS t,
    UNNEST(t.hits) AS hits
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('Asia/Tokyo'), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(REGEXP_REPLACE(URL, r '(.+)\&is\_true\=0', ""),r '^\/aaaa\/bbbb\/cccc\?.*')
GROUP BY
    t.date,
    pagepath
```

どなたか正解をご存知でしたら教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 正規表現の部分だけではなくて全体のSQLも書いてもらってもよいですか？

Comment: 追記いたしました！よろしくお願いします。

Comment: URL パラメータの並び順は常に固定とは限らないので、順番が前後して `?is_true=0&parameter=0` のような URL が含まれる可能性もありますが、こちらは考慮されていますか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます、たしかにそのようなケースもあるので考慮できると最高によいですが、今回の場合は稀なのでできなくてもいいです。